# MS Access VBA DLookup Function Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have created a couple of functions to determine the permission level of a user in MS Access.  I have a table called tblEmployees that contains the following fields: (FirstName, LastName, Email, Role, Login, PermissionLevel).

I have created this function to determine the "Login" (this works fine every time):

```
Option Compare Database Public intPermissionLevel As Integer

Public Function getUserName() As String  
     getUserName = Environ("USERNAME") 
End Function
```

I have then created this function to lookup the permission level using the value supplied for the "Login" field by the getUserName function above.  The correct value is passed into the "LookupPermissionLevel" function, however I am getting the following error every time.  (ct627 is my username and it is included in the tblEmployees)

"The expression that you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'ct627'"

```
Public Function LookUpPermissionLevel(getUserName As String) As Integer        
      intPermissionLevel = DLookup("PermissionLevel", "tblEmployees", "Login =" & getUserName)

End Function
```

Comment: add another `'` after getusername

Comment: I tried adding a single quote before getUserName, after getUserName and both before and after getUserName.  I also tried all combinations with double quotes.  None of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function LookUpPermissionLevel(getUserName As String) As Integer        
      intPermissionLevel = DLookup("PermissionLevel", "tblEmployees", "Login ='" & getUserName & "'")
LookUpPermissionLevel=intPermissionLevel
End Function
```

Comment: add another ' before getusername ;-)

Comment: I tried adding a single quote before getUserName, after getUserName and both before and after getUserName.  I also tried all combinations with double quotes.  None of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were actually both correct.  Thank you!  This was what I needed to do:

```
intPermissionLevel = DLookup("[PermissionLevel]", "tblEmployees", "[Login]='" & getUserName & "'")
```